# 404 Error on form submission within custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, 404-error, forms

I'm trying to create a forum system using WP's custom post types - two post types as Topic/Reply and a Forum taxonomy.

I have created a singular template for the topic post type, in which I added a reply form.
The problem is that when I submit the form I get a 404 page.

This is the form template:

```
<div class="topic-reply-form">
  <form method="post" name="topic-reply-form" class="topic-reply-form clear-block" action="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>">
    <p><?php _ae("Add reply"); ?></p>
    <fieldset>
       <textarea id="reply-content" name="content" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
       <input type="hidden" name="topic" value="<?php the_ID(); ?>" />
       <?php wp_nonce_field('new-topic-reply'); ?>
       <input type="submit" value="Publish" id="reply-submit" name="reply-submit" />
    </fieldset>
 </form>
</div>
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Please add your solution as answer so question can be properly resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was the "topic" name field. It seems you can't use [reserved terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms) in $_POST, and "topic" is a post type name, so its probably one of them...

Answer (score 1):

FYI to anyone else who finds this, also be mindful of how you name your nonces. If there's a conflict WP won't recognize the logic in your page that verifies the nonce. It'll give you a 404.

Not fun.